# How to replace all the values of a list upto a certain index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How to replace all the values of a list upto a certain index to ceratin value or item? If the input is:

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Lets say the index we chose is `2` and we want to replace with `$`. So, the output should look like:

```
list_op = ['$', '$', '$', 'd']
```

Can we achive this python standar functions?

Comment: yes, please make an attempt before asking

Comment: @depperm I am looking for standard functionalities. Not to  write a function or so.

Answer (score 1):

you can use slice assignment:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
lst[:3] = 3 * ["$"]
print(lst)  # ['$', '$', '$', 'd']
```

this means: replace the first 3 elemennts of `lst` (which is `lst[:3]`) with `3 * ["$"]` (which is `['$', '$', '$']`).

if you only wanted to replace the 2 middle elements:

```
lst[1:3] = 2 * ["$"]
# ['a', '$', '$', 'd']
```

also note that [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#func-list) is a built-in function in python and therefore not a good variable name.